# Cloud Kit's performQuery in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

---

Hi.
I'm trying to make Cloud Kit based app. For data fetch I'm using this

```
privateDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) {
        results, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            print(results)
            for item in results {
                self.workoutData.append(item as! CKRecord)
            }
        }
    }
```

but XCode says

> '[CKRecord]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Can you help me please?

Comment: What line does this appear on?

Comment: for item in results {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unwrap the CKRecord array like so:

```
if let res = results {
    for item in res! {
        //Do things with item
    }
}
```